# Graphical NSDatePicker and separate days

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Is there a way to select separate days in a graphical NSDatePicker ?

Example : I would like to select days 3, 5 and 18 from August.

For now, I'm only able to select range from 3 to 18.

Any idea ?

Thanks.

Comment: NSDatePicker is just a NSStepper paired with an NSTextField. How would you be able to specify specific dates? You might need to make your own control here or use augmented standard controls.

Comment: With the Graphical style and 'Date Range' option for Selects.

Comment: Oh got ya. So something like shift click to select multiple days? What delegate methods does that control provide; first place to look.

Comment: Nope... I've already try with the shift, ctrl, option and cmd keys.

Comment: Yes I understand. Is that the behaviour you want to implement? First you need to see if you can control the select dates? What kind of methods are provided for this purpose? If that fails are there delegate methods you can implement?

Comment: You can only use setDateValue: and setTimeInterval:

Comment: Just checked. I can't see a way of doing this with the available methods.

Comment: So, any idea to extend the standard one ?

Comment: No I don't think it is possible with the exposed functionality.